# get xml from webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I need to call a web service, that returns this xml

```
<Response>
    <statusCode>OK</statusCode>
    <statusMessage/>
    <ipAddress>127.0.0.1</ipAddress>
    <countryCode>-</countryCode>
    <countryName>-</countryName>
    <regionName>-</regionName>
    <cityName>-</cityName>
    <zipCode>-</zipCode>
    <latitude>0</latitude>
    <longitude>0</longitude>
    <timeZone>-</timeZone>
</Response>
```

This is the URL:

```
String userIp = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
// api key
String api_key = "01cce0db52b4eafaf8eac3f5b560fa4b5bf20f1410763224557d05eb949a2b3c";
// service url
String api_url = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=" +api_key +"&ip="+ userIp +"&format=xml";
```

How can I catch that in asp? I tried with a web service but can't figure it out.

Comment: Does the XML change by input parameters or URI path?

Comment: @SliverNinja I've added the code for the  URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use John Saunders approach and call [`WebClient.DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do something like this...

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string result = client.DownloadString(api_url);
```

The string `result` should then hold the downloaded content from the url.